# Dynamic Structure in c#

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I need to create a dynamic structure that contains rows. (Includes a row of titles).

Each row has columns: some of the string columns, and some is list .

The number of columns and their type changes each run, because it depends on the file that sendto the program as a parameter.

How can I create such a structure?

Thank you

Comment: What you describe sounds like a csv parser

Comment: DataTable is such dynamic structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0) represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time. Whereas the [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) keyword is used to declare variables that should be late-bound. These will be the two building blocks.

Here's an example that presents the basic mechanics:

```cs
dynamic user = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();  
user.Name = "John Doe";  
user.Age = 42;
user.Cars = new List<string>() {"Ferrari", "Porsche"};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in user)
{   
    if (kvp.Key == "Cars") {
    Console.WriteLine($"I have {((List<string>)kvp.Value).Count} {kvp.Key}");
    } else { 
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
    }
}

// Dynamic Add
user.Address = "3 Frozen Land";

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in user)
{   
    if (kvp.Key == "Cars") {
    Console.WriteLine($"I have {((List<string>)kvp.Value).Count} {kvp.Key}");
    } else { 
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
    }
}

// Dynamic Remove 
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)user;
dict.Remove("Age");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in user)
{   
    if (kvp.Key == "Cars") {
    Console.WriteLine($"I have {((List<string>)kvp.Value).Count} {kvp.Key}");
    } else { 
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

That will produce the following:

[image]